# AWS EKS- EBS CSI add-on degraded and failed to come active state

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-eks

I have created the EKS cluster in AWS console

The cluster is created in two private subnets and NAT-gateway is attached to its route table of those private subnet

And create the node group with instance type as c5.xlarge and came to active state

Now I am created the add-on with custom OIDC provider role AWS_VPC_CNI and AWS_EBS_CSI

AWS_VPC_CNI add-on is came to active state but AWS_EBS_CSI is degraded with following error "The add-on is unhealthy because it doesn't have the desired number of replicas"

In the OIDC provider addon role for AWS_VPC_CNI the following aws managed policy is attached AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy and attaching the trust relationship of role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountNumber>:oidc-provider/<OIDC ID>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "<OIDC ID>:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com",
                    "<OIDC ID>:sub": "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:aws-node"
                }
```

Similarly for AWS_EBS_CSI role the following aws managed policy is attached AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy and one more custom policy is attached as following

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:DetachVolume",
                "ec2:ModifyVolume",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumesModifications"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:snapshot/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": [
                        "CreateVolume",
                        "CreateSnapshot"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:snapshot/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/CSIVolumeName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CSIVolumeName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CSIVolumeSnapshotName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And attaching the trust relationship of AWS_EBS_CSI role as following,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::279649766383:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.ap-south-2.amazonaws.com/id/84F15F13C79758077B521DE9FA0AE8FB"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.ap-south-2.amazonaws.com/id/84F15F13C79758077B521DE9FA0AE8FB:sub": "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa",
                    "oidc.eks.ap-south-2.amazonaws.com/id/84F15F13C79758077B521DE9FA0AE8FB:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried by updating the add-on to latest version and done all possibility ways but still my AWS_EBS_CSI driver addon is degrading

Please help me solve the above issue

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for your problem, I'm facing the same.

Comment: I think data nodes are required to work ebs csi and other addons

Answer (score 0):

IAM role and it”s trustrelationshitp are likely correct.
Can you share pod description and service account “ebs-csi-controller-sa” description.

Otherwide, make sure that OIDC Identity provider is attached.

Comment: worker nodes are required to have ebs-csi pod?

Comment: Not required if you are using IAM role for service account attached to EBS csi driver pods. The idea behind IRSA is attaching specific role to pod instead of assuming node role by all pods running on top of this node.